# Adding a function curve to ggplot, not with geom_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am trying to add my Bayesian logistic curve to the output I already have. For context, the coefficients of my output lead me to an equation of: y = -2.53 + .0003*x

[Plot without function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gGhr.png)

Here is what I have tried, and I am getting the following error:

[failed function, nothing ran for the function/line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngDdW.png)

And I do not want to use geom_smooth, as it does the following which is not the EXACT points that would be on the line. Help anybody?

[geom_smooth not getting the job done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVPAH.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as images - copy it directly into the post

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `bayesian` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).